# How to override wndProc in a non settable control

Tags: c#, event-handling, devexpress

I have a `XtraGrid` and some columns can get masked depending on the value of another column.
I managed to achieve it by seting the mask in the editor in the `CustomRowCellEdit` event.

Snipet below:

```
private void myGridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "MyTargetField")
    {
        GridView gv = sender as GridView;
        var typeValue = gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["MaskOrNotDependsOnThisField"]);

        if (typeValue == DynamicMask)
        {

            var maskToApply = GetMaskForThisValue(gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["MyTargetField"]));

            RepositoryItemTextEdit riMaskedTextEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
            riMaskedTextEdit.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.Simple;
            riMaskedTextEdit.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
            riMaskedTextEdit.Mask.SaveLiteral = false;
            riMaskedTextEdit.Mask.EditMask = maskToApply;
            e.RepositoryItem = riMaskedTextEdit;
            //riMaskedTextEdit.KeyDown += EditorKeyDownDinamicMask;
        }
    }
}
```

It worked like a charm but some masks can be dynamic (hey I don't make the requeriments!).
So I uncomment that event handler line and created a `KeyDownEventHandler`.

Let's say my mask changes as user keeps typing like:

> 999.999 for 6 digits
>
> 999.999-9 for 7 digits
>
> 999.(999)/99 for 8 digits

Note I need to use KeyDown because the mask can prevent the ValueChanged event to fire.
I handled the keydown and managed to put this thing to work fine.

Question is:**How to handle Paste events?**
(from both keyboard and mouse paste events)

I know how to override **wndProc** in a control, I already did it a few times before.
Problem here is `RepositoryItemTextEdit` class is not a control with a wndProc to override.
I digged a bit and found the above class has a

```
public TextEdit OwnerEdit { get; }
```

And that is the real guy handling the events.
Unfortunately devxpress left it as a non settable member.

Right now user cannot replace the 999.999 value with a 999.999-9 in copy paste because the mask truncates the pasted value.
Note it also prevents the ValueChaged event to fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RepositoryItemTextEdit` class is used to hold the properties for in-place instance of `TextEdit` class. Technically `TextEdit` class is box which holds the instance of `TextBoxMaskBox` class. `TextBoxMaskBox` class is inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` class.
So, you can create your own `RepositoryItemTextEdit`, `TextEdit` and `TextBoxMaskBox` descendants and override `WndProc` method in your own `TextBoxMaskBox` descendant.
Here is example:

```
[UserRepositoryItem("RegisterPasteHandlerEdit")]
public class RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit : RepositoryItemTextEdit
{
    static RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit()
    {
        RegisterPasteHandlerEdit();
    }

    static private readonly object EventPaste;

    public const string CustomEditName = "PasteHandlerEdit";

    public RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit() { }

    public override string EditorTypeName => CustomEditName;

    public static void RegisterPasteHandlerEdit()
    {
        Image img = null;
        EditorRegistrationInfo.Default.Editors.Add(new EditorClassInfo(CustomEditName, typeof(PasteHandlerEdit), typeof(RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit), typeof(TextEditViewInfo), new TextEditPainter(), true, img));
    }

    public override void Assign(RepositoryItem item)
    {
        BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            base.Assign(item);
            var source = item as RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit;
            if (source == null) return;

            Events.AddHandler(EventPaste, source.Events[EventPaste]);
        }
        finally
        {
            EndUpdate();
        }
    }

    public event PasteEventHandler OnPaste
    {
        add
        {
            Events.AddHandler(EventPaste, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            Events.RemoveHandler(EventPaste, value);
        }
    }

    protected internal void RaiseOnPaste(PasteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsLockEvents)
            return;

        var handler = (PasteEventHandler)Events[EventPaste];
        handler?.Invoke(GetEventSender(), e);
    }
}

[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class PasteHandlerEdit : TextEdit
{
    static PasteHandlerEdit()
    {
        RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit.RegisterPasteHandlerEdit();
    }

    public PasteHandlerEdit() { }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public new RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit Properties => base.Properties as RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit;

    public override string EditorTypeName => RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit.CustomEditName;

    protected override TextBoxMaskBox CreateMaskBoxInstance() => new PasteHandlerMaskBox(this);

    protected override void CreateMaskBox()
    {
        base.CreateMaskBox();

        var pasteHandlerMaskBox = MaskBox as PasteHandlerMaskBox;
        pasteHandlerMaskBox.OnPaste += PasteHandlerMaskBox_OnPaste;
    }

    private void PasteHandlerMaskBox_OnPaste(object sender, PasteEventArgs e) => Properties.RaiseOnPaste(e);
}

public class PasteHandlerMaskBox : TextBoxMaskBox
{
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

    public PasteHandlerMaskBox(TextEdit ownerEdit) : base(ownerEdit) { }

    public event PasteEventHandler OnPaste;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            var e = new PasteEventArgs();

            OnPaste?.Invoke(this, e);

            if (e.Cancel)
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}

public class PasteEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    public PasteEventArgs() { }
    public PasteEventArgs(bool cancel) : base(cancel) { }

    public string Text => Clipboard.GetText();
}

public delegate void PasteEventHandler(object sender, PasteEventArgs e);
```

In this example the `OnPaste` event is added to `RepositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit` class. You can use this:

```
private void repositoryItemPasteHandlerEdit1_OnPaste(object sender, PasteEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Text);

    if (...) // Perform some checks.
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```